# Toolbar appear at the top instead of at the bottom

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I am trying to have **2 toolbars**, one at the top and the other one at the bottom of the screen. Currently the bottom one is still showing at the top. How do I solve it ?

*activity_main.xml*

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.x.fresh.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*toolbar_bottom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

Comment: Can you include `toolbar_bottom` inside `content_main`?

Comment: It is still the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using relativeLayout then `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` has no meaning.

Use this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.x.fresh.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<include layout="@layout/content_main"
           android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:id="@+id/content"/>

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what is the appbar?<include layout="@layout/content_main"
           android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:id="@+id/content"/>

Comment: @purplewind appbar is the id of `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

Comment: do u mean the id for the top toolbar ? it already has been declared as seen <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

Comment: @purplewind As your top toolbar is in app bar and in parent relative layout there is appbar(top toolbar), content and below toolbar. so for content below toolbar I have used `android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"`. Also as top toolbar and content are not in same parent but appbar and content are in same parent that's why I have used id of appbar. Hope you understood , for any problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

hi please below example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include
            layout="@layout/test"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottombar"
            layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Just Add relative layout

You can check screen shot[image]

Comment: yes i already did, as seen in my code example above. I added in the <include> tag

Comment: hi please check out my example for this, just add relative layout inside cordinatorLayout or you can use Relative layout instead or Cordinator layout

Comment: @roman_empire Hi.You have added two answers please delete one of them or merge them.Thanks